# IIS 7 Print in not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, printing

I am trying to print a document which is working fine in my Visual studio 2010 application but when i am publishing my project on IIS 7 then printing is not working and i cant see any error in the event viewer .

```
MyProcess = new Process();
MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
MyProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = destinationPath;
MyProcess.Start();
MyProcess.WaitForExit(10000);
MyProcess.Close();
```

Comment: Where do you expect this to print? "The default printer"? The default printer of which user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running in Visual Studio, you're running as a logged-in, interactive user.

When you're running in IIS, well, you're not any of the above.

---

The way this is normally done in a web application is to:

1. Display the document to the user in the browser
2. Print the document by using the ['window.print'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print) function from JavaScript.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Please answer my comment above (where do you expect it to print)?

Comment: to the default printer i am sorry i am new in .net

Comment: and the default printer of the logged in user

Comment: There is no such thing as "the default printer". There is such a thing as "the default printer for a given user". You want to print to the default printer of which user? The user using the web site?

Comment: That is not possible to do from a web application. Consider that the web server may not even be in the same domain as the logged in user.

Comment: Actually i am developing a web application for a school and it would only be used locally not over the internet

Comment: "Never over the Internet": famous last words. This assumption fails as soon as a student wants to use your application from his laptop in his favorite restaurant which has WiFi, or even from his mother's house while he's visiting.

Comment: it would be used by the school management and it is nothing to do with the student so the client requirement is to run locally

Comment: Same thing. Now it's the school secretary using the application from the local coffee shop. I strongly suggest you get away from that assumption. Furthermore, everyone is used to how the Internet works. I strongly suggest you make even internal application behave like everyone expects, which is what I added to my answer, above.

Comment: yes you are right now what should i do to solve this problem any suggestions?

Comment: can i ask you one more thing? actually my scenerio is i am using openxml to write values from the database in to a word document .What i am trying to do now is to open the document replace bookmarks from values then closing the document and then print the document but there can be thousands of documents like this

Comment: That's a separate question and you should ask it separately. Briefly (or in case I don't see your new question), that's not a problem if you're doing this because the user logged in at the browser asked you to do so. You will be able to print one document at a time this way. If you have to do this for many documents at once, then you need a different solution. You would need to do something like launch a desktop application, logged in as the user, which would use MS Word to automatically print the set of documents.

Comment: If you have a library which can do this without Word, that would work too, but the big change is that the program doing the printing would have to be logged in interactively as the user, in order to use the user's default printer.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still cares for an answer..
I had the same problem, solution was to give IIS user access to use installed printers on the computer. When you print from IIS , you're logged in as a system default user who by default doesn't have proper printer access setup in the registry.You need to give printer access to the default system user by adding few entries in the registry. Just follow this tutorial like I did http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=184291.
It will fix it.

Comment: Of course, now you have a security problem because you have allowed a user from the Internet to access your printer. In fact, depending on _how_ you gave access to the printer, you may have given access to much more than just the printer. Now your authentication not only needs to be good enough to protect your application, it also needs to be good enough to protect the resources on your network, like the printer.

Answer (score 1):

If the printer is not installed on the server, nothing is going to happen.

If you're trying to print from ASP.NET code to a printer attached to the client computer it's never going to work. The server cannot get to and use any resources on the client computers.

2nd and important thing change to LoadUserProfile to true in IIS Application pool.